# Inconsistent Snapchat Ads behavior on Android: Redirecting to Playstore instead of opening the app directly, regardless of app installation status

Tags: android, redirect, deep-linking, snapchat

I've encountered a perplexing issue with Snapchat Ads on Android devices. It appears that regardless of whether the app is already installed on the user's device or not, clicking on the ads always redirects them to the Playstore. This inconsistency is not only causing inconvenience for users but also hampering the overall user experience.

Ideally, the ads should seamlessly open the app if it's already installed on the user's device and redirect to the Playstore only when the app is not installed. However, this is not the case currently, and it's posing a significant problem.

I'm seeking insights and solutions to resolve this issue and ensure that Snapchat Ads behave consistently by opening the app directly when it's already installed and redirecting to the Playstore only for users who don't have the app installed. Any suggestions or guidance on how to address this matter would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

I have tried implementing both standard deep links using the "https" scheme (https://example.com/some-endpoint) and custom scheme (myapp://example.com/some-endpoint). These deep links have been correctly declared in the AndroidManifest.xml as follows:

```xml
<data android:scheme="https" android:host="example.com" android:pathPattern="/some-endpoint" />
<data android:scheme="myapp" android:host="example.com" android:pathPattern="/some-endpoint" />
```

When testing these deep links independently, they work flawlessly, correctly opening our app if it is installed on the device or redirecting to the Playstore for installation if the app is not present.

However, the problem arises when I include these deep links in Snapchat Ads. Regardless of whether the app is already installed or not, clicking on the Snapchat Ads always leads to redirection to the Playstore, rather than opening the app directly.

Expected Behavior:
I expected that when incorporating these deep links into Snapchat Ads, the behavior would align with their standalone behavior. Specifically, when the app is already installed on a user's device, clicking on the Snapchat Ads would directly open the app. For users who do not have the app installed, the deep links should redirect to the Playstore for installation.

Snapchat Documentation: https://businesshelp.snapchat.com/s/article/deeplink-specs?language=en_US